# What is the max effective limit of luck of the sea in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I made a fishing rod with the luck of the sea enchantment at around 2.1 billion. The fishing rod works as normal, except it doesn't catch anything. I read on the wiki that a fishing rod won't work with lure above level 3, is there something similar for luck of the sea?

Comment: I suggest enchanting your rod level by level. If you reach a certain level that the rod no longer works as intended, then that's your answer. You can self-answer, so you can show what you tried. I can't right now because I'm kinda tired.

Answer (score 3):

Trial and error has confirmed the fishing rod stops working past level 84 of luck of the sea.

Answer (score -1):

Sadly, you can only have three of each.